# MachineName for remote machine using Remote Desktop

Tags: c#, .net, windows, remote-desktop

I'm writing a C# program where it would be useful to see if someone is running the program via remote desktop and if so, the machine name where the remote desktop is running.

I can get the former using `SystemInformation.TerminalServerSession`

But is there any way to get the name of the remote machine?

Comment: I asked the same question - see my answer here...

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147904/c-sharp-determine-remote-desktop-login-users-computer-name][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147904/c-sharp-determine-remote-desktop-login-users-computer-name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the Remote Desktop Services API will do what you want...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383468(v=VS.85).aspx

And the following example may help too - http://community.citrix.com/display/xa/How+to+get+client+IP+address+and+client+hostname+using+Terminal+Services+API

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly use [WTSQuerySessionInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383838%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get this information, though if you'd prefer not to deal with the P/Invokes, you could also use the [Cassia library](http://code.google.com/p/cassia/): `new TerminalServicesManager().CurrentSession.ClientName`.